# how to print in new column if the nth character is reached in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print in new column if the nth character is reached But i didnt got output

Input:

```
5
['c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'o', 'e'
```

output needed:

```
c f e
o i
d l
e r
f o
```

my code:

```
n=5

l= ['c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'o', 'e']
for i in range(0,len(l)):
  print(l[i])
  if i%n==0 and i!=0:
    print('\r')
```

output got:

```
c
o
d
e
f
f

i
l
r
o
e
```

What mistake i made??

Comment: It is not clear how you are supposed to get that expected output

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey i changed the code sir please check now

Comment: I need to print in new column if the nth character is reached. But my code printing in the same column

Comment: You need to print a new column every n characters?

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey yes

Comment: This might help: [Vertically print a list of strings to STDOUT into 3 columns with column lengths as balanced as possible](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188353/vertically-print-a-list-of-strings-to-stdout-into-3-columns-with-column-lengths)

Answer (score 1):

You can't go back and print to a line you've already printed. But you *can* append to a list you've already created. This means you need to save data into a structure first, then print.

So, you need to find a way to loop through the data once and collect the rows into groups so at the end you can loop through them and print. There's a lot of ways to do this. Here's one that uses some of the ideas you already have:

```
n = 5
l = ['c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'o', 'e']

rows = []
for i, c in enumerate(l):
    if i % n >= len(rows): # if row doesn't exist
        rows.append([])    # make a new one 
    rows[i%n].append(c)    # then append

# now that it's restructured into rows, print
for row in rows:
    print(" ".join(row))
```

This should print:

```
c f e
o i
d l
e r
f o
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a list and storing rows in it like below

```
grid=[]
n=5
l= ['c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'o', 'e']
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    if i//n==0:
        grid.append(l[i])
    else:
        grid[i%n]=grid[i%n]+l[i] 
for row in grid:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution based on list comprehension and slicing. It takes the `n`th characters from the string with the initial offsets on 0,1,...,n-1.

```
print("\n".join([" ".join(l[i::n]) for i in range(n)]))
#c f e
#o i
#d l
#e r
#f o
```

Comment: This is succinct and elegant. Curious though…is it quadratic in complexity?

Comment: Probably. But since `print` is insanely slow, who cares?

Comment: Like I said…just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to print() must output all the letters to show on the line.  Printing cannot move backward:

```
n = 5
a = ['c', 'o', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'r', 'o', 'e']

for i in range(n):
    print(*a[i::n])

c f e
o i
d l
e r
f o
```